# Certain CSS3 Animations not working in firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, firefox

Some of my animations work, and others don't. They all work fine in Chrome. Here's the one that doesn't work:

```
.orbit {
position: absolute;
height: 810px;
width: 810px;
top: 50px;
left: 200px;

border-radius: 8%;
border:0px solid red;

margin-left: -100px;
margin-top: -100px;

-webkit-animation-duration: 160s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-name: spinleft;

-moz-animation-duration: 160s;
-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
-moz-animation-delay: 0s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-name: spinleft;

animation: spinleft 160s linear 0s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinleft {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes spinleft {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spinleft {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
```

I've tried a million combinations of laying out the animations and they just don't work. Weirdly, these animations do work:

```
.charanimate{
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s; 
-webkit-animation-name: appear;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

-moz-animation-delay: 0s;
-moz-animation-duration: 3s; 
-moz-animation-name: appear;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

animation-delay: 0s;
animation-duration: 3s; 
animation-name: appear;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

@-webkit-keyframes appear { 
 from { 
    left: -240px; 
    top: 465px; 
 } 
 70%{
    left:50px;
 }
 to { 
    top:465px;
    left: 35px;
 } 
} 

@-moz-keyframes appear { 
 from { 
    left: -240px; 
    top: 465px; 
 } 
 70%{
    left:50px;
 }
 to { 
    top:465px;
    left: 35px;
 } 
} 

@keyframes appear { 
 from { 
    left: -240px; 
    top: 465px; 
 } 
 70%{
    left:50px;
 }
 to { 
    top:465px;
    left: 35px;
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly change the `-webkit-` prefix to `-moz-` here:

```
@-moz-keyframes spinleft {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
```

And remove the `-webkit-` prefix here, so it is `transform: rotate(-360deg);` instead:

```
@keyframes spinleft {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't I feel like an absolute idiot! Thank you so much.